# Print FontImage more than once

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

```
[Button1][1]
```

Image of Button1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tK7O.png

Codenameone Gurus, why am I not able to output the same Image twice? Is there a proper way to output the image more than once.

And dont tell me its because the line is commented haha
Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

A component can only be added to one parent UI. That's core to Codename One and many GUI toolkits such as Swing, AWT etc.

Since a component has a parent (see `getParent()`) it can only have one parent but multiple children.